# Remove Proxy Classes Generated During Mapping in Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am working on Fluent Nhibernate and getting the following error:
No persister for: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Customer_3FF392FD8867C34D66C0BEB65D29B9B13BAFD2651E0DD73A797E67ADE1455B21

Please tell me that how can I remove the proxy that are generated during mapping. Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call:

`session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.Unproxy(entity)`